# How to Pass Dictionary between two different routes in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to pass a dictionary(JSON) variable between two routes.  I tried it using session but failed.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    #here i am getting my json_var from an website's api.
    json_var = requests.get(api_url).json()

    session['json_var'] = json_var
    #Note Line 1
    pprint(session['json_var'])
    return render_template('..some template..')

@app.route('/home')
def home():
     #Here I want to access, that json_var saved in session here.
    json_dict = session.get('json_var')
    #Note Line 2
    pprint(json_dict)
    json_dict = --some sorting in json_var--
    return render_template('....')
```

Results of print below *Note Line 1* is the json response as a wanted.
But results of print below *Note Line 2* is exactly same json dict that we get when we query from an wrong thing from api ie, an empty dict with messages of "Not found".

Comment: Could you describe the problem in a bit more detail with an example of what the JSON object will contain?

Comment: Did you tried `global` variables ? It may work.

Comment: I am getting saving my json_obj variable from a website's api. In "index" view I am saving it directly from that website. But once i have saved my json_obj. I want it in another view like "Home" to show some other details.I hope this will clear the problem.

Comment: Rahul K P can you describe how to do it by global variable?

Comment: @RahulKP please don't suggest things like that. It would be horribly unsafe.

Comment: @H.G. you should show how you "tried and failed" using the session.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for the point, I would like to know the security issues with global sharing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I update the problem. hope it will help.

Comment: Are these methods members of an object? You could save the data in a member.

Comment: @FullName I am not getting, what do you want to know?

Comment: Do you know about classes an objects?

Comment: @FullName yes! But these two functions are not defined in any class.

Comment: Then you should do this. Then you can save the data as a member of this class.

Comment: @FullName again, please don't recommend things like this. Keeping any kind of state between requests *must* be done in the database or other external storage.

Comment: @H.G. what happened when you tried this session code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman 'json_dict' becomes empty when accessing it into '/home' route. it is showing message exactly equals to when I access api and results not found. I am confused that why it is happening because in '/' route it is working properly and saved in session.